# Parsing HTML within Javascript button elements with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been parsing Craigslist using Requests and BeautifulSoup. I can access posts and everything, but when trying to access a post's 'reply' email address, I can't seem to return anything -- assumedly because you must first 'click' the reply button.

What I'd like to do is some how get this email address. Using

```
reply = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'anonemail'})
```

or

```
reply = soup('button',{'class':'reply_button js-only'})
```

or any variation of this on elements containing the email address return nothing.

I can manually access reply urls such as:

http://losangeles.craigslist.org/reply/lax/sof/4869445564

but I can't seem to find out how this url is generated dynamically. That is, I could manually supply /reply/lax/solf/(dataid) at the end of the url, but I want to know how to extract this url from the page itself, unless, again, there's an easier way to access the reply email address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = 'http://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sof/4869468306.html';
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read());
reply = soup.findAll('a', attrs = {"id": "replylink"});
if reply:
   url = 'http://losangeles.craigslist.org' + reply[0].get('href');
   soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read());    
   reply = soup.findAll(['div', 'a'], attrs = {"class": re.compile(r'anonemail|mailapp')});
   if reply:
      reply[0].getText()
```

returns:

```
u'qx8ft-4869445564@job.craigslist.org'
```

Comment: this also gives me no result unfortunately

Comment: hmm, I'll try and give you an answer

Comment: This is close, but my problem is getting the reply url (the one you use in your answer) from the page at the post url (http://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sof/4869468306.html). It seems to come down to getting that region abbreviation (lax) but I don't know where it comes from and it's different from post to post, so iterating through posts, you don't know what suffix it's going to use beforehand

Comment: ooh, now I understand, so if you look to  the source the email is not there, you need to inspect how that result is obtain when you click the button, give me some minutes

Comment: so you know this link http://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sof/4869468306.html?, If this is the case with regex \d+ get the id and visit the page http://losangeles.craigslist.org/reply/lax/sof/id

Comment: it's the '/lax/' part that's throwing me off, just after '/reply/'

Comment: here is what is in the source code <span class="replylink"><a id="replylink" href="/reply/lax/sof/4869468306">reply</a></span> so you could reply = soup.findAll('a'), attrs = {"id": "replylink"}); and then reply[0].get('href') and, so the final link is http://losangeles.craigslist.org/ + the result

Comment: Have you tried this to see if it works? Cause I'm still getting no result

Comment: if you post your full code I'll tell you, by the way do you understand mine?

Comment: I typed it interactively into the command prompt and it worked, and I've been working though the problem that way, so maybe something I entered long ago is what messed me up.

Comment: url = 'http://losangeles.craigslist.org/wst/sof/4869468306.html';            request = requests.get(target_url);                                                            soup=BeautifulSoup(request.text.encode('utf-8'));  post=soup.findAll('a',attrs={"id":"replylink"})   This always gave no result

Comment: when you want to scrape some website first thing is to study the source code, network traffic when you do something in that website, use chrome's developer tools

Comment: I was, and also fwiw I was using Requests library instead of urllib